# sort list of lists in ascending and descending order with strings

Tags: python, sorting

I was looking into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666748/python-sort-list-of-lists-ascending-and-then-decending) question about sorting a list of lists with multiple criteria (element 0 descending and element 1 ascending) .

```
L = [['a',1], ['a',2], ['a',3], ['b',1], ['b',2], ['b',3]]
L.sort(key=lambda k: (-k[0], k[1]), reverse=True)
```

is there a way to make it work when the first or the second element is a string?

Comment: Python handles string sorting. Have you tried this code? What is the desired output?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6667177/3270800 should work.

Comment: I don't see the problem here? The code you give works just fine

Comment: `L.sort()` changes L rather return a new list.

Comment: it complains about using unary operator '-' with strings

Comment: @TanveerAlam yes, but I was trying to do it in one line

Answer (score 4):

It is simple, just use `-ord` for your strings:

```
L.sort(key=lambda k: (-ord(k[0]), k[1]), reverse=True)
```

Output:

```
In [1]: L = [['a',1], ['a',2], ['a',3], ['b',1], ['b',2], ['b',3]]

In [2]: L.sort(key=lambda k: (-ord(k[0]), k[1]), reverse=True)

In [3]: L
Out[3]: [['a', 3], ['a', 2], ['a', 1], ['b', 3], ['b', 2], ['b', 1]]
```

You can get the exact same result by not using reverse and negating the int values:

```
L = [['a',1], ['a',2], ['a',3], ['b',1], ['b',2], ['b',3]]

L.sort(key=lambda k: (k[0], -k[1]))

print(L)
[['a', 3], ['a', 2], ['a', 1], ['b', 3], ['b', 2], ['b', 1]]
```

So for a mixture of strings and ints you don't actually need cmp, ord or anything other negating the int values.

Answer (score 1):

As you want to reverse the sort order for the second string, using the `key` function won't work. However, using the `cmp` function will work:

```
L.sort(cmp=lambda x, y: cmp(x[0], y[0]) or -cmp(x[1], y[1]))
```

Comment: I'm not sure I got it. could you modify the example in case element 1 is a string and element 0 is a number? thank you,

Comment: cmp no longer exists in python3, there is also no need to use cmp at all

Comment: Sorry, I did not see that the question was about python 3.x, I still have 2.7 here.

Comment: @Bob: cmp does not care about type as long as it is innately comparable. So it should not matter if it's a number or string.