# How to sort a list of lists by one element ascending and another descending

Tags: python, list, sorting

I need to order lists inside of a list by the numbers in decreasing order. If the number is the same, I have to order it in alphabetical order (increasing).

For example if I have the following list:

```
mylist=[['a', 5], ['l', 2], ['u', 1], ['t', 1], ['q', 1], ['o', 1], ['e', 1]]
```

The output has to be like this:

```
[['a', 5], ['l', 2], ['e', 1], ['o', 1], ['q', 1], ['t', 1], ['u', 1]]
```

I have searched for this, but I can only found how to order a list. The problem here is that I have to order it by the alphabet just when the number is the same. So the order is first by the numbers (I´ve reached that already), and then I have to order it but the alphabet when the numbers are the same.

Comment: Have you searched for how to sort lists?

Comment: why does `['y', 0]` come after `['z', 0]`? I do not understand how you want this list to be sorted.

Comment: Are you asking how to sort only *part* of the list (those with the second element = 1), leaving the rest unchanged?

Comment: I think converting it to a dictionary format would be a lot easier to implement and think. Does dictionary approach make sense for this use case?

Comment: I have searched for this, but I can only found how to order a list, but the problem here is that I have to order it by the alphabet just when the number is the same. So the Order is first by the numbers (I´ve reached that already), and then I have to order it but the alphabet when the numbers are the same.

Comment: Yes pault that´s exactly what I need to do

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python sort list of lists / ascending and then decending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666748/python-sort-list-of-lists-ascending-and-then-decending)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to sort by the second element (number) descending and by the first element (letter) ascending alphabetically.

This should get what you're looking for:

```
mylist = list=[['a', 5], ['l', 2], ['u', 1], ['t', 1], ['q', 1], ['o', 1], ['e', 1]]
sorted_list = sorted(mylist, key = lambda x:(-x[1], x[0]))
print(sorted_list)
#[['a', 5], ['l', 2], ['e', 1], ['o', 1], ['q', 1], ['t', 1], ['u', 1]]
```

We use the `key` argument to `sorted` to define how to sort the list. In this case, we pass in a lambda function `lambda x: (-x[1], x[0])` as the key function. The "trick" here is that we pass in the negative of `x[1]` (negative of the number) so that it sorts by the number descending. The second element of the tuple `x[0]` is the character, which will serve to break ties for list elements with the same number value.

Comment: @JamesPaul a great explanation is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8966627/5858851)

Comment: How would I order with the same conditions but with the reverse order of the alphabet?

Comment: There are two ways that I can think of. 1) If you want to sort descending by both number and letter: pass in `reverse=True` to `sorted()` and remove the negative sign: `sorted(mylist, key = lambda x:(x[1], x[0]), reverse=True)`. 2) Another way is to convert the letter to an ordered numerical representation using `ord` and negate it: `sorted(mylist, key = lambda x:(-x[1], -ord(x[0])))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `key` keyword-only argument to change how `list.sort` evaluates each element of the list. In this case you want it to evaluate the second element of each sublist, or `sublist[1]`.

```
# don't use `list` as a variable name, it shadows the builtin
lst.sort(key=lambda sublst: sublst[1])
```

or using `operator.itemgetter`:

```
from operator import itemgetter

lst.sort(key=itemgetter(1))
```

Comment: The question also asks that the result be alphabetized, but the given expected output does not do this so I'm ignoring that part of the requirement

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get more sophisticated you could define a class that defines the '<' operator in the way you want. Then you can either pass a list of instances of your new class to sorted. Or you use the class constructor to generate keys.

For this simple example this seems to be overkill though.

```
class Foo(list):
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self[1] > other[1] or (self[1] == other[1] and self[0] < other[0])

sorted(l, key=Foo)
```