# Suggestion on picking the best options of two lists (minimum and maximum )python

Tags: python, genetic-algorithm

I have three lists, each list has 200,000 item. The first list titled 'config' is a list of configuration names (these are window blind configuration). The second list has the illuminance performance of each configuration (same order, meaning that config_a001 yields illuminance value of 350). The last list has a value for each config (same order as well, so config_002 has a value of 0.24)

```
config = ['config_a001', 'config_a002', ......]
illuminnace = [350, 376, 260, 500, 450,......]
LUR_value = [0.3,0.24,.7,.1,.....]
```

I need to pick the best 5 configurations that yield the highest illuminance and lowest LUR value. If this is not possible, I need to pick the best 5 configurations with the lowest LUR value but their illuminance should be higher than a specific threshold, let's say 450.

I know that things like this should be solved using a genetic algorithm but I'm experienced in this area, I'd appreciate it if anyone here provides a suggestion.

Comment: `zip` the lists together, and then use `(illuminance, -LUR_value)` as your key function.  Then you can just take the slice of the first 5 elements.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666748/python-sort-list-of-lists-ascending-and-then-decending

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider organizing the data into a pandas DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

config = ['config_a001', 'config_a002', 'config_a003', 'config_a004', 'config_a005', 'config_a006']
il = [350, 376, 310, 340, 290, 375]
lur = [0.3, 0.24, 0.21, 0.31, 0.24, 0.28]
```

Create a Dictionary of your lists

```
d = {'config': config, 'il': il, 'lur': lur}
```

Create a DataFrame object from your dictionary

```
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Use `sort_values()` and slice the top 5 results from the `config` column:

```
res = df.sort_values(['il', 'lur'], ascending=[False, True])[:5]['config'].values
```

This provides a numpy array with config values.

```
list(res)
# Result: ['config_a002', 'config_a006', 'config_a001', 'config_a004', 'config_a003']
```

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
config = ['config_a001', 'config_a002', 'config_a003', 'config_a004','config_a005']
illuminnace = [350, 376, 260, 500, 450]
LUR_value = [0.3,0.24,.7,.1,.3]
```

If 'optimization' is the highest `illuminnace` with the lowest `LUR_value` you can zip the lists together to form tuples of the data:

```
>>> list(zip(config,illuminnace,LUR_value))
[('config_a001', 350, 0.3), ('config_a002', 376, 0.24), ('config_a003', 260, 0.7), ('config_a004', 500, 0.1), ('config_a005', 450, 0.3)]
```

And then sort those with a `key` function:

```
>>> sorted(zip(config,illuminnace,LUR_value),key=lambda t: (-t[1],t[2]))
[('config_a004', 500, 0.1), ('config_a005', 450, 0.3), ('config_a002', 376, 0.24), ('config_a001', 350, 0.3), ('config_a003', 260, 0.7)]
```

If you want to filter, add a expression after the `zip` but before `sorted` to filter on the relevant criteria:

```
>>> sorted((t for t in zip(config,illuminnace,LUR_value) if t[1]>=450),key=lambda t: (-t[1],t[2]))
[('config_a004', 500, 0.1), ('config_a005', 450, 0.3)]
```

If you have more complicated grouping criteria, either write a custom key function for sort that expresses it or consider using [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby). Your current example data is not complete enough to give an example.