# Problem with sorting with multiple criterias in Python

Tags: python, list, sorting

I am trying to sort a list composed of names and grades:

`[['Harry', 37.21], ['Berry', 37.21], ['Tina', 37.2], ['Akriti', 41.0], ['Harsh', 39.0]]`

I want to sort them first according to the grades and then if the grades are the same, according to the alphabetical order of their names. I tried the following code but it is not working for the name sorting part. Can you tell me the problem please.
Thank you

```
score_list=[]
for _ in range(int(input())):
    name = input()
    score = float(input())
    score_list.append([name, score])

score_list.sort(key = lambda x: (x[1], x[0]), reverse=True)
```

Comment: What's your desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THE PERFECT SOLUTION  (1st answer from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666748/python-sort-list-of-lists-ascending-and-then-decending))

```
score_list = sorted(score_list,key = lambda x: (-x[1], x[0]))
```

or (my way):

```
score_list = [j[::-1] for j in sorted([i[::-1] for i in l],key=lambda x: (-x[0],x[1]))]
```

gives: your desire:

```
[['Akriti', 41.0], ['Harsh', 39.0], ['Berry', 37.21], ['Harry', 37.21], ['Tina', 37.2]]
```

---

EXAMPLES
Here is how you do that:

```
sort_ list = [j[::-1] for j in sorted([i[::-1] for i in l])]
```

This gives:

```
[['Tina', 37.2], ['Berry', 37.21], ['Harry', 37.21], ['Harsh', 39.0], ['Akriti', 41.0]]
```

Here:

```
l = [['Harry', 37.21], ['Berry', 37.21], ['Tina', 37.2], ['Akriti', 41.0], ['Harsh', 39.0]]
```

Now if you want it in descending order:

```
sort_ list = [j[::-1] for j in sorted([i[::-1] for i in l],reverse = True)]
```

This gives:

```
[['Akriti', 41.0], ['Harsh', 39.0], ['Harry', 37.21], ['Berry', 37.21], ['Tina', 37.2]]
```