# Sort List of dicts first in ascending order of a key and then in descending order of another key

Tags: python

I have a list of dicts like this:

```
[{"x" : 5 , "y" : 7} , {"x" : 4 , "y" : 3} , {"x" : 4 , "y" : 7}]
```

I want to sort them first in ascending order of x and then in descending order of y so that the result is

```
[{"x" : 4 , "y" : 7} , {"x" : 4 , "y" : 3} , {"x" : 5 , "y" : 7}]
```

I can sort both in ascending order by

```
sorted(a , key=lambda k: (k['x'] , k['y']))
```

or in descending order by

```
sorted(a , key=lambda k: (k['x'] , k['y']) , reverse=True)
```

Is there a good way to sort by x ascending and y descending here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort list of lists ascending and then descending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666748/sort-list-of-lists-ascending-and-then-descending)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are sorting by number, you can just multiply by `-1` to reverse the order:

```py
>>> a = [{"x" : 5 , "y" : 7} , {"x" : 4 , "y" : 3} , {"x" : 4 , "y" : 7}]
>>> sorted(a , key=lambda k: (k['x'] , k['y'] * -1))
[{'x': 4, 'y': 7}, {'x': 4, 'y': 3}, {'x': 5, 'y': 7}]
```

You can also add `-` before the variable and it will work the same way as multiplying by `-1`:

```py
>>> sorted(a , key=lambda k: (k['x'] , -k['y']))
[{'x': 4, 'y': 7}, {'x': 4, 'y': 3}, {'x': 5, 'y': 7}]
```