# How to do a multi level sort on list of lists in Python?

Tags: python, nested-lists

I have the below code:

```py
lst = [['candy','30'], ['apple','10'], ['baby','20'], ['baby','10']]
lst.sort(key=lambda x: (x[1], x[0]))
print(lst)
```

With this the output is:

```py
[['apple', '10'], ['baby', '10'], ['baby', '20'], ['candy', '30']]
```

I'm trying to display the names in Descending order while the values in Ascending order. Is there a pre built way in python to achieve this?

Expected output:

```py
[['baby', '10'], ['apple', '10'], ['baby', '20'], ['candy', '30']]
```

Comment: What would your expected output be? Also list of lists? Or just print it that way

Comment: What should be the output for `[['a', '1'], ['b', '2'], ['c', '3']]`?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233476/sort-a-list-by-multiple-attributes

Comment: @DanielF No it's not. I did my search and didn't find any multi sort. Like I asked in my question, i want one in ascending and one in descending order.

Comment: @Pramod updated my answer, now matches your expected output.

Comment: "Like I asked in my question, i want one in ascending and one in descending order." The approach is the same (it's just a matter of making the key for the descending-order sort, compare in the opposite order, e.g. by using a numeric negative); and also the question title doesn't adequately convey that aspect of the requirements.

Comment: But perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666748/sort-list-of-lists-ascending-and-then-descending is a more specific duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You changed the expected output, this would be the solution for that:

```
lst.sort(key=lambda x: (-int(x[1]), x[0]), reverse=True)
#[['baby', '10'], ['apple', '10'], ['baby', '20'], ['candy', '30']]
```

This was the answer before the question was edited and seperates the entries before sorting them:

```
print(*zip(sorted([x[0] for x in lst], reverse=True), sorted([x[1] for x in lst])))
# ('candy', '10') ('baby', '10') ('baby', '20') ('apple', '30')
```

Comment: Awesome.. the edited answer did the job. Thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by reverse sorting by name and negative value:

```py
>>> lst = [['candy','30'], ['apple','10'], ['baby','20'], ['baby','10']]
>>> lst.sort(key=lambda x: (x[0], -int(x[1])), reverse=True)
>>> lst
[['candy', '30'], ['baby', '10'], ['baby', '20'], ['apple', '10']]
```

Edit: In response to OP's edit, value should take priority over name, so the correct order is:

```py
>>> lst = [['candy','30'], ['apple','10'], ['baby','20'], ['baby','10']]
>>> lst.sort(key=lambda x: (-int(x[1]), x[0]), reverse=True)
>>> lst
[['baby', '10'], ['apple', '10'], ['baby', '20'], ['candy', '30']]
```

Comment: The values are not in displayed in ascending order, though.

Comment: @enzo That is another possible interpretation. I read it as "sort these (name, value) pairs by descending name and ascending value", but if they can be disassociated, then that approach is good.

Answer (score 1):

You can try setting `reverse = True`.

```
lst = [['candy','30'], ['apple','10'], ['baby','20'], ['baby','10']]
lst.sort(key=lambda x: (x[1], x[0]), reverse=True)
print(lst)
```